# Объединение значений Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, список, множества

Доброго времени суток!

Есть список словарей:

```
local = [{'Client': [70, 242],
  'description': 'name123',
  'userNotes': 'snq'},{'Client': [70, 169],
  'description': 'name234',
  'userNotes': 'e123123'}]
local_2 = [{'descriptionTag': 'Test1', 'Client': 169},
 {'descriptionTag': 'Test2', 'Client': 242},
 {'descriptionTag': 'Test3', 'Client': 70}]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно можно соединить значение 'Client' ?
В первом словаре есть 'Client' и список чисел, а во втором есть расшифровка этих чисел.

В итоге должно получиться так:

```
local = [{'Client': ['Test3', 'Test2'],
      'description': 'name123',
      'userNotes': 'snq'},
         {'Client': ['Test3', Test1],
      'description': 'name234',
      'userNotes': 'e123123'}]
```

- нужно условие если не нашел ключ во втором поставил ' No key '
  Недавно начал изучать питон, не знаю как правильно еще описать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с толковых наименований переменных, а то в дебрях этих local'ов легко запутаться `(:` Переименовал, не уверен, что в соответствии с вашей задаче, но работать с кодом стало куда проще. А для решения подобных задач часто бывает полезным создавать промежуточные структуры данных и функции, которые упростят последующий алгоритм, в данном случае это `client_to_tag` и `update_user_clients`:

```py
users = [{
    'Client': [70, 242],
    'description': 'name123',
    'userNotes': 'snq'
}, {
    'Client': [70, 169],
    'description': 'name234',
    'userNotes': 'e123123'
}]
tags = [
    {'descriptionTag': 'Test1', 'Client': 169},
    {'descriptionTag': 'Test2', 'Client': 242},
    {'descriptionTag': 'Test3', 'Client': 70},
]

client_to_tag = {
    d['Client']: d['descriptionTag']
    for d in tags
}

def update_user_clients(user):
    user = {**user}
    user['Client'] = [
        client_to_tag[client]
        for client in user['Client']
    ]
    return user

updated_users = [
    update_user_clients(user)
    for user in users
]
print(updated_users)
```

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на заметку!!

Comment: А куда надо прописать условие, если ключа нет во втором списке то он бы присвоил любой знак?